# Hopping a VPN Tunnel

Tags: vpn, routing

My central office and remote offices are connected to each other over site to site ipsec vpn. We use Fortigate firewalls and everything is working fine. On the other hand, only central office is also connected to another company's network over ipsec vpn as well. In this situation, everything is also fine and employees at the central office is able to reach the other company's resources without problem. Now i want the employees working on our remote office can reach the other company's network over central office without creating new vpn tunnels.

[http://imgur.com/ozrXfGv](https://imgur.com/ozrXfGv)

How can i do that?
Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPSec tunnels are generally specific not only to destination IP address, but also to source IP address as well.  Some people think of them as tubes with a funnel on each end, down which packets can be poured to emerge from the other end; like all simplifications, this can sometimes be unhelpful, and this is one such case.

If you have the ability to perform SNAT on traffic from your remote office at your IPSec endpoint, so that to both tunnel and remote company's network the traffic appears as if it came from your central office, then it may be possible to route that traffic down the tunnel, and get responses.  Otherwise, it is not likely to be possible without adding additional tunnels that cover the remote office's IP address range.  In that latter case you would likely need to check that the remote company network will correctly route this new netblock as well.